# Find $\omega$ such that the sum of the tangential and normal components of acceleration equal half its speed.

Tags: vector-analysis

**Problem:** Given the following position vector of an object in space: 
$$R(t)=(a\cos(\omega t),a\sin(\omega t),\omega^2 t)$$
Find $\omega\neq0$ such that the sum of the tangential and normal components of acceleration equal half its speed.

I computed the tangential $A_T$ and the normal component of the acceleration $A_N$ and got the following expressions 
$$A_T=a\omega\sqrt{\omega^2+4}$$
$$A_N=\omega\sqrt{\frac{a^4\omega^2+2a^2\omega^2t^2+4a^4+8a^2t^2-4t^2}{a^2+2t^2}}$$
which is, unfortunately, leading to an extremely big polynomial equation that I am unable to resolve. I am guessing that the answer is much simpler, so please correct me if I am making a mistake.

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make sense, since acceleration and velocity have different units.

Comment: @Travis please see the edit.

Comment: The objection still holds. Also, $R$ seems to be recorded incorrectly in the problem statement, the third component is $\omega^2 t$, not $\omega^2$. At any rate, $|R'|^2 = R' \cdot R'$ is a constant, so the tangential acceleration is zero, no?